# Any break statement for tt:loop in ST Transformation?

Tags: xml, loops, abap, abap-st

Any control break statement for `tt:loop` in XML Simple Transformation in ABAP?

I would like to find a specific row while looping data in `tt:loop` in XML Simple Transformation in ABAP.

Ex:

[image: 1]

Here I want to find every last record based on STUDENT_ID while looping..
i.e

```
7000 80
8000 89
```

Comment: You can simply initialize a variable with last row and compare it with current row.

Comment: try using AT END OF.